# Limited number of js include files in an HTML5 webpage on Android

Tags: javascript, html, webview, include, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing an iOS/Android app by using HTML5, JS and CSS3 in a WebView. iOS devices and phones with Android 2.x work without any problems. But tablets equipped with Android 3.x or 4.x do not load the webpage.

Basically I am building a webpage like this

```
<html lang="en" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; display:block;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">
        <title>Project Name</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="File1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="File2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="File3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="File4.js"></script>
            ...
    <body style="margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden">
    </body>
</html>
```

(in total, 25 javascript file includes)

I have overwritten WebViewClient::onPageStarted, WebViewClient::onReceivedError, WebViewClient::onPageFinished. WebViewClient::onPageStarted gets called and the LOG shows the javascripts being loaded. But WebViewClient::onPageFinished never gets called and the webpage does not build. The window "load" callback does not happen and therefore none of the js files get executed.

So, I put an alert popup into my window "load" function and removed one file after the other to see if this helps. And indeed this helped. When I only include 4-6 files the window "load" function gets called. But this is also somehow random and does not depend on which files I remove. LOG does not show any error either. Everything seems to be fine

Is there any limit in number of include files introduced in Android 3.x and later? Android 2.x works without any problem. Also Chrome and Safari on my desktop PC display the site without any errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the limit, but I would suggest using [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) on your js files to get around this issue.

Comment: Ok, this is what we do already (on our buildserver). Unfortunately this does not improve anything regarding Android 3.x/4.x devices.

Comment: @Hanzano - no worries, sorry couldn't offer further help

Comment: No prob. I appreciate any kind of a hint. I am stuck on this since weeks ;)